# Can I use Highspeed Opamp as differential clock driver?

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, camera, optoelectronics, ccd

I want to use high speed Opamp LT1364 as +/- 15V clock driver of same voltage instead of typical CMOS / CCD clock drivers with lower voltage and slew rate.

CMRR : 90dB
PSRR : 100dB
Slew rate : 1kV/uS

Please help me with which other parameter shall I consider for choosing correct OpAmp

Comment: But how fast is your clock and what are you going to drive with it?

Comment: What is your input voltage to the LT1364? Do you have a circuit proposal?

Comment: @pipe My end device clock is between 1MHz to 20 MHz and CCD sensor I have to drive

Comment: @Andyaka I want to convert pulse input (CMOS 3.3V) from controller to +/- 15V signal using this OpAmp

Comment: *I want to convert pulse input (CMOS 3.3V) from controller to +/- 15V signal* To me that sounds like a job for a **level shifter** rather than an opamp. For +/- 15 V (so 30 V) from 3.3 V you need 10x gain. GBW of the LT1364 is 70 MHz so that means this could "work" up to 70 MHz / 10x = 7 MHz. You want 20 MHz which is about 3x more. Conclusion: using this opamp is not a good idea. A "better" opamp will also not help much. Use a levelshifter!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie how about a totem-pole driver?

Comment: @rdtsc how about it? A totem-pole driver is just a that, a driver. Show me a totem-pole driver which can output 0 V to 15 V when driven from 0 V to 3.3 V. You still need some form of level shifting.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the timing requirements of the clock signal you want to generate: minimum high time, minimum low time, maximum rise time, maximum fall time. It would be best if you would provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the CCD.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bimpelrekkie I've found a lot but was not able to find perfect level shifter. It would be great if you can suggest one level translator / levelshifter